# Short story about decoding pre-Edison music recordings found in an attic in Paris

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm pretty sure it was an Australian author. My first guess was Sean Williams, second guess Greg Egan, but I cannot recognise the story in their bibliographies. Most likely published in the 1990s. I think I read it in "Aurealis".

The story involves a man (a sound engineer, I think) visiting a relative in Paris and finding or being shown a box of silver discs that supposedly had music recordings on them. He and a friend develop a way to play the discs. They contain many recordings of the great composers and performers of the early 19th century (or maybe earlier). The point is, they were recorded before Edison invented the phonograph. The last disc they listen to is called something like "To my friend", and it does not contain music but a voice recording from the woman to her "friend" --- the person who would learn to play back the recordings she had made --- begging him to publish the recordings of her own playing (she was really good, but could not perform publicly in her time, because of a scandal).

There was a note from the author about the origin of the story coming from having a fever (in Darwin?) and hearing Puccini playing as if hearing it through time.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: In fact, someone did record sound before Edison but had no way of playing the recording: https://www.nps.gov/edis/learn/historyculture/origins-of-sound-recording-edouard-leon-scott-de-martinville.htm#:~:text=Edouard%2DL%C3%A9on%20Scott%20de%20Martinville%20invented%20sound%20recording%2020%20years,it%20both%20visible%20and%20permanent. There were many smart people that most do not know about or do not know the full extent of their contributions.

Comment: There's a 2020 story ("Wheels of Echoes") by Australian author Sean McMullen with pre-Edison recordings, but it otherwise doesn't fit.

Comment: That's basically the technique used, except the discs were coated in silver not soot (necessary to last in an attic until the 20th century). I don't recall any explanation as how the woman was able to make the silver coated glass discs.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, Sean McMullen was the key. This is really embarrassing --- I have completely confounded the two names in my head.  "Wheels of Echoes" is not the answer. But "The Colours of the Masters" is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about science fiction or fantasy as described in the site guidelines.

Comment: I think this is very marginally science fiction. According to the link posted by another user, the first *known* sound recording device was likely created four or five years after the death of Chopin by a forward-thinking inventor. This is such a small gap that it does not feel very speculative that another forward-thinking inventor might have created something similar a few years earlier. Maybe they did. This seems less "futuristic technology" (for the time) and more "showing Sheldon deriving known research results on *The Big Bang Theory*." Unless the device was invented well before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Colours of the Masters](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?844110) by Sean McMullen.

I read it in the anthology [Glass Reptile Breakout](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?15504), and my copy does not have notes by the authors. However the story matches. The sound engineer is Rico and he is shown the disks by a couple of spinsters living in an old mansion in Paris:

> I turned to the door, only to be confronted by a pair of elderly identical twins. The women would have been in their early seventies, and were dressed in smart grey suits and frilly white blouses.
>
> “We have mechanical recordings of Frederic Chopin playing his own piano works,” said the one on the right in confident English.
>
> “We are not, ah, whackos,” said the other, her voice and accent identical. “I am Claudine Vaud, and this is my sister Charlotte.”
>
> “We are very respectable. We do not even know how to hold a seance,”
> Charlotte stated indignantly.
>
> I was taken aback. “Edison got the prototype of his phonograph working in 1877,” I replied. “Chopin died thirty years before that.”
>
> “Twenty eight years,” Charlotte smugly corrected me.
>
> “But an ancestor of ours invented a way to record sound — except that she could not play it back,” continued Claudette

The mention of the disk titled *"To My Friend"* is:

> I volunteered to stay and help, and we set about taping another half dozen disks that Katherine had made in her later years. The last disk of all was dated only three weeks before her death, and was titled “To My Friend”.

Comment: Yes. @Andrew gave me the clue. I have completely confounded Sean McMullen and Sean Williams in my mind. As soon as I searched for the correct Sean I found it.

Comment: Glad to help out